# Recommendations for OpenGL / Scheme combination

Tags: opengl, scheme

I'd like to try out OpenGL programming in Scheme.

Can anyone give a recommendation for a decent Scheme compiler / OpenGL library combination?

I have no reservations, though it would be *nice* (but not a requirement) to be able to produce native, executable binaries — primarily on Windows, but also on UNIX and/or Mac OS X.

EDIT: Changed to community wiki, since the question does not have a definite answer I can accept.  Thanks for the replies!

Comment: If you ask for native you have to specify the platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PLT Scheme](http://plt-scheme.org/) includes [OpenGL bindings](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/sgl/overview.html) in 2 forms, one that matches the C API, and one that's more "scheme" like in usage.

**Update**: PLT Scheme is now known as Racket, which also has [OpenGL bindings](http://docs.racket-lang.org/sgl/overview.html).

Comment: These days the opengl library can be found with `(require opengl)`.

Answer (score 2):

[Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-with-current-continuation.org/) has an [egg](http://chicken.wiki.br/eggref/4/opengl) that provides OpenGL bindings. IMHO, it's not well documented; if you are not familiar with OpenGL already, then this library isn't the right place to start learning.

Answer (score 2):

[Spark Scheme](https://github.com/vijaymathew/spark-scheme):

> Spark-Scheme is a dialect of Lisp, which gives you...
>
> - Interactive, modular software development
> - Meta-programming facilities
> - Advanced control flow
> - Distributed computing
> - A comprehensive networking API
> - **A modern GUI framework**
> - **2D/3D graphics**
> - An SQL database engine and connectivity to third-party databases
> - A web server and a couple of web application frameworks

Comment: You're the author?  Looked at Spark scheme, it looks really nice!

Answer (score 1):

Gambit-C Has some "3rd party" Open GL bindings, available in the [dumping grounds](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/wiki/index.php/Dumping_Grounds).